# Differential equation for auditory system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, signal-processing, control-theory, biology

Let $x$ and $y$ be input and output signals, respectively. A simple low-pass filter [satisfies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter#Simple_infinite_impulse_response_filter)

$$ y' = k (x - y) $$

where $k > 0$. A simple high-pass filter [satisfies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-pass_filter#Discrete-time_realization)

$$ y = k (x - y)' $$

The [gammachirp filter](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7535/6ff909f5bc9cb0ab740e1a225a45defb9e38.pdf) is a widely used model of the auditory system. Its [impulse response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_response) is

$$ h(t) = \Re(\exp(z_1 + z_2 t + z_3 \ln t)) $$

where $z_1, z_2, z_3 \in \mathbb{C}$. What differential equation does it satisfy? In general, what differential equation do [auditory filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_band#Auditory_filters) satisfy, approximately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$t\frac{d}{dt}h(t)=(z_{2}t+z_{3})h(t)$$